# Prove that $\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\cdots+\sqrt{x_n} \geq (n-1) \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}} \right )$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, radicals, sum-of-squares-method, rearrangement-inequality

> Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n > 0$ such that $\dfrac{1}{1+x_1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{1+x_n}=1$. Prove the following inequality.
> $$\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\cdots+\sqrt{x_n} \geq (n-1) \left (\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_1}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}} \right ).$$

This is Exercice 1.48 in the book "Inequalities-A mathematical Olympiad approach".

**Attempt**

I tried using HM-GM and I got $\left ( \dfrac{1}{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2n}} \geq \dfrac{n}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_1}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}}} \implies \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_1}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_1}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}} \geq n(x_1x_2 \cdots x_n)^{\frac{1}{2n}}$. But I get stuck here and don't know if this even helps.

Comment: from where does this come?

Comment: An inequality book.

Comment: Would you mind to tell us title and author? Does that book contain solutions or hints? – Or is this meant as an exercise for us?

Comment: It was a problem my instructor gave me, and I don't know where he got it from. We must figure this out ourselves.

Answer (score 11):

Note that $\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{1+a_i} = 1 \implies \sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i} = n-1$. Then, $$\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^n \sqrt{a_i}-(n-1)\sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{1+a_i}\sum \sqrt{a_i} - \sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i} \sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}} = \displaystyle \sum_{i,j} \dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}} = \sum_{i>j} \dfrac{(\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}-1)(\sqrt{a_i}-\sqrt{a_j})^2(\sqrt{a_i}+\sqrt{a_j})}{(1+a_i)(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}}$$

But $1 \geq \dfrac{1}{1+a_i}+\dfrac{1}{1+a_j} = \dfrac{2+a_i+a_j}{1+a_i+a_j+a_ia_j}$ thus $a_ia_j \geq 1$. Hence the terms of the last sum are positive.

Answer (score 11):

Rewrite our inequality in the following form:
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i+1}{\sqrt{x_i}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i+1}\geq n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i}}$,
which is Chebyshov.

Comment: But to use Chebyshev, you need the terms to be decreasing, right? It's not necessarily true.

Comment: To Vinícius Novelli. If $x_1\leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n$ so $x_2\geq\frac{1}{x_1}>1$

Comment: It was for $x_1<1$. But If $x_1\geq1$ it's obvious.

Comment: $\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}}$ decreases for $x<1$. So the Chebyshev does not apply directly.

Comment: What do you think of my comment above?

Comment: @Hans See please my previous comments.

Comment: Ingenious proof! +1

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I know this answer is old, but I posted a question (4807666) and the answer redirected to this topic. Your proof seems incorrect. I tried in the same way proving my inequality and I encountered a problem. Your inequality is false. Fore example n=2, $x_1=0.1$, $x_2=1$. These numbers don't satisfy the condition but your proof doesn't use it in proving your inequality.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, now I see you're right. Namely, if $x_1<1$ then $(x_1+1)/\sqrt{x_1}\leq (x_2+1)/\sqrt{x_2}$, although the function isn't monotone. I think this observation could be placed in your answer. Thank you for your solution.