# Prove that $\frac{\sum_\text{cyc} x_1}{2020^2} \geq (n - 1)(\sum_\text{cyc} \frac{1}{x_1})$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $0 \lt x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le ... \le x_{n - 1} \le x_n$ and $n \geqslant 2$.

Also , $$\sum_\text{cyc} \frac{1}{x_1^2 + 2020^2} = \frac{1}{2020^2}$$

Prove that $$\frac{\sum_\text{cyc} x_1}{2020^2} \geq (n - 1)(\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{x_1})$$

This is problem #5 (Afternoon) Thailand POSN Camp 2.

Can anyone give me any hints (or solutions) please. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always noticed how they put the year in the question. I see that it is worthless. Write $2021$ in place of $2020$ and it won't change a thing :p
\begin{align*}
\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{x_1^2 + 2020^2} &= \frac{1}{2020^2}\\
\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{\frac{x_1^2}{2020^2}+1} &= 1\\
\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{x^\prime_1+1} &= 1\\
\end{align*}
where $$x^\prime_i=\frac{x_i^2}{2020^2}\Rightarrow \frac{x_i}{2020}=+\sqrt{x^\prime_i}\quad(\because x_i>0)$$.

So, we need to prove
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sum_\text{cyc} x_1}{2020} &\geq (n - 1)(\sum_{cyc} \frac{2020}{x_1})\\
\text{or}\quad\sum_\text{cyc} \frac{x_1}{2020} &\geq (n - 1)(\sum_{cyc} \frac{2020}{x_1})\\
\text{or}\quad\sum_\text{cyc} \sqrt{x^\prime_1} &\geq (n - 1)(\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^\prime_1}})\\
\end{align*}
Now, [Prove that $\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\cdots+\sqrt{x_n} \geq (n-1) \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}} \right )$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593036/prove-that-sqrtx-1-sqrtx-2-cdots-sqrtx-n-geq-n-1-left-frac1)

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality is true for any positive variables such that:$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{x_1^2 + 2020^2} = \frac{1}{2020^2}.$$

Indeed, let $a_i=\frac{x_i^2}{2020}$ and see here: [Prove that $\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\cdots+\sqrt{x_n} \geq (n-1) \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}} \right )$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593036)

Comment: Can you give more specific detail please.

Comment: Do we have to use Chebyshev? Sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: @Ivar the Boneless Yes we can. See my post in the linked topic.

Comment: Get it! Thank you very much.